# Check if data exists

Tags: php, api

I'm working with an API.

With an array I collect data like this:

```
$org_payload = array(
        'name' => $_POST['billing_company'],
        'phone' => $_POST['billing_phone'],
        'email' => $_POST['billing_email'],
        'note' => $_POST['order_comments'],
        'relation_type' => array(
            'id'=>'relationtype:c1ec3ae77036842d' //provide the relationtypeid, f.e. relationtype:796ce0d318a2f5db515efc18bba82b90
        ),
        'visiting_address' => array(
            'country_code'          =>  'NL',
             'line_1'               =>  $_POST['billing_address_1'],
             'postal_code'          =>  $_POST['billing_postcode'],
             'locality'             =>  $_POST['billing_city'],
             'country'              => $_POST['billing_country']

        ), // can be extented with other address data
        'postal_address' => array(
            'country_code'          =>  'NL'
        ) // can be extented with other address data
);
```

At one point i send this data to the program i'm working with. I achieve this with this code:

```
$organization = $SimplicateApi->makeApiCall('POST','/crm/organization',json_encode($org_payload));
```

I gather this data from a form on my website. This data gets posted in the program.

I am trying to achieve that when data gathered from my form matches existing data in the program then don't add it.  I would like a hint in the right direction for this, been looking on the internet without any luck.

Comment: use `curl` to make post requests from PHP

Comment: Create your own database and store the records there. Check each submitted record against what you've stored before posting to the API.

Comment: @PatrickQ i think this is the answer i've been looking for, thanks mate.

Comment: is there something unique in the form for each submit ?

Comment: @VasilShaddix Company name and phone number.

Comment: @PatrickQ i know this answer is solved, but apparently i can just use a get request to get data and then check if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is to have one extra call to the API.

Like you said in the comments - the company name and the phone number is unique.
If there is some call to get a user by those values and check what you got from the form, would be enough.

If they are unique - send them,
if not - show to the user or whatever you want to do here.

No need to keep one more database on your system as well.